# Invalid Property Value CSS in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to achieve the following in the top section an image to show where the "breadcrumb" is. I have it highlighted in the image.

[image: What I want to achieve see the highlighted section]

The css for it is:

```
.breadcrumbs-v3.img-v3 {
    background: url(../img/breadcrumbs/img3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

When I translate the css into rails acceptable format it looks like this:

```
.breadcrumbs-v3.img-v3 {
  background: url(<%= asset_url 'creative/martin_images/img3.jpg' %>) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Instead of seeing the image I want to see I only see this with the following error message:

> Invalid Property Value

See the console for the error message far right.

[image: Error]

In my stylesheets folder I am loading the css into my layouts which include the about.index.html where the code resides.

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require creative/bootstrap.min
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require creative/animate
 *= require creative/animated-headline
 *= require creative/custom
 *= require creative/dark
 *= require creative/default
 *= require creative/footer-v1
 *= require creative/header-v6
 *= require creative/jquery.fancybox
 *= require creative/line-icons
 *= require creative/owl.carousel
 *= require creative/parallax-slider
 *= require creative/settings
 *= require creative/style
 *= require creative/app
 *= require creative/blocks
 *= require creative/page_log_reg_v1
 *= require creative/page_about
 *= require creative/jquery.mCustomScrollbar
 *= require creative/sky-forms
 *= require creative/custom-sky-forms

 *= require_self
*/
```

Here is my layout view creatives.html.erb.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= yield(:page_title) %> | </title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'creative/manifest.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'creative/manifest.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <!-- GOOGLE FONT -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&amp;subset=cyrillic,latin'>

</head>

<body class="header-fixed-space-default">
<%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>

<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

</body>
</html>
```

Could someone please help me figure out why I am not able to imitate the first picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inlcude erb tags `<%= %>` in your stylesheet.

To correctly link an image in your css, you use:

```
.selector {
   background-image: url(/assets/image.png);
}
```

or

```
.selector {
   background-image: url("/assets/image.png");
}
```

Comment: You were right...I had to make an adjustment if I put "assets/creative/martin_images" the address came out as "assets/creative/assets/creative" so I just made it martin_images. I updated my question to reflect that.